# Scrapy: Rules set inside __init__ are ignored by CrawlSpider

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been stuck on this for a few days, and it's making me go crazy.

I call my scrapy spider like this:

```
scrapy crawl example -a follow_links="True"
```

I pass in the "follow_links" flag to determine whether the entire website should be scraped, or just the index page I have defined in the spider.

This flag is checked in the spider's constructor to see which rule should be set:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.follow_links = kwargs.get('follow_links')
    if self.follow_links == "True":
        self.rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback="parse_pages", follow=True),
        )
    else:
        self.rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*')), callback="parse_pages", follow=False),
        )
```

If it's "True", all links are allowed; if it's "False", all links are denied.

So far, so good, however these rules are ignored. The only way I can get rules to be followed is if I define them outside of the constructor. That means, something like this would work correctly:

```
class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*')), callback="parse_pages", follow=False),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

So basically, defining the rules within the `__init__` constructor causes the rules to be ignored, whereas defining the rules outside of the constructor works as expected.

I cannot understand this. My code is below.

```
import re
import scrapy

from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from w3lib.html import remove_tags, remove_comments, replace_escape_chars, replace_entities, remove_tags_with_content


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']    
    # if the rule below is uncommented, it works as expected (i.e. follow links and call parse_pages)
    # rules = (
    #     Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback="parse_pages", follow=True),
    # )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # single page or follow links
        self.follow_links = kwargs.get('follow_links')
        if self.follow_links == "True":
            # the rule below will always be ignored (why?!)
            self.rules = (
                Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=()), callback="parse_pages", follow=True),
            )
        else:
            # the rule below will always be ignored (why?!)
            self.rules = (
                Rule(LinkExtractor(deny=(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]*')), callback="parse_pages", follow=False),
            )


    def parse_pages(self, response):
        print("In parse_pages")
        print(response.xpath('/html/body').extract())
        return None


    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        print("In parse_start_url")
        print(response.xpath('/html/body').extract())
        return None
```

Thank you for taking the time to help me on this matter.

Comment: can you try setting your rules before calling `super(ExampleSpider,...`?

Comment: @eLRuLL, you should post this as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that `CrawlSpider` constructor (`__init__`) is also handling the `rules` parameter, so if you need to assign them, you'll have to do it before calling the default constructor.

In other words do everything you need before calling `super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` :

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # setting my own rules
    super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: This is it exactly. You have to set up your rules, start_urls and allowed_domains before calling super().